# Why for var in array returns a string index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

I've been really surprised that, in Javascript:

```
> vals = ["a", "b", "c"]
> for (v in vals) console.log(v + 1)
01 
11 
21
```

this because:

```
> for (v in vals) console.log(typeof(v))
string
string
string
```

so I'm forced to do something like:

```
> for (v in vals) console.log(parseInt(v) + 1)
1 
2 
3
```

**Why this happens?**

I know I can do

```
> for (var v = 0; v < vals.length; v++) console.log(v + 1)
1 
2 
3
```

but being used with python my mind is set with `for ... in ...` iteration

Comment: *"...but being used with python my mind is set with `for ... in ...` iteration"* Python is irrelevant here. This is JavaScript. All object properties are strings. Use a `for` loop.

Comment: ...there are several reasons in JS to us `for` instead of `for-in` on Arrays. However, if you really want to do it that way, you can shorten it to `console.log(+v + 1);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My friend, behold the wonder and curse of prototypical inheritance. What you are iterating over with `for..in` isn't an array. You are iterating over an Array object. Take a look at the doc:

> Array indexes are just enumerable properties with integer names and
>   are otherwise identical to general Object properties. There is no
>   guarantee that for...in will return the indexes in any particular
>   order and it will return all enumerable properties, including those
>   with non–integer names and those that are inherited.
>
> Because the order of iteration is implementation dependent, iterating
>   over an array may not visit elements in a consistent order. Therefore
>   it is better to use a for loop with a numeric index (or Array.forEach
>   or the for...of loop) when iterating over arrays where the order of
>   access is important.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

So what you are dealing with are enumerable "integer names" of properties in an Array object, not numerical order.

**EDIT** `for v in array` in JavaScript isn't equivalent to `for v in list` in python. It's equivalent to `for k, v in dict.iteritems()` but k is implicitly given to you as a string with integer name so to speak, i.e. "1", "2", "3", etc. I think it's counter-intuitive as well from an OO standpoint. How can a list/array be a dict-like object? But from a prototypical standpoint, so  long as anything inherits from `Object.prototype`, it can be considered an Object with keys and properties.